# What do I use as a parameter for the setOnClickListener() method?

Tags: android, button

I'm trying to make multiple OnClickListener methods for 5 buttons in my program, and I've been able to declare them, and I made a switch using the xml id of what was clicked, but I need a parameter for the setOnClickListener method when I call it, and all that will work is null.  I have also tried passing in this, so the method has context.

Here's some of the code:

```
 add.setOnClickListener(null);
        sub.setOnClickListener(null);
        mult.setOnClickListener(null);
        div.setOnClickListener(null);
        equal.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Answer (score 3):

The parameter has to be an instance of some object that implements the `OnClickListener` interface. One way to do it is to use an anonymous inner class:

```
add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
  public void onClick(View view){
//your event handler code here
}
});
```

another way is to make your class implement `OnClickListener` --do that by changing your declaration to look like:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
```

then define an implementation for the onClick method:

```
public void onClick(View view){
   if(view == add){
      //handle add button click
    }else if (view == sub){
      //handle sub button click
    }
    //etc

}
```

then to install the listener you could do:

```
add.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what I settled on what this: I declared the listener and the name of an event handler method within the XML, as follows:
android:onClick="clickHandler"/>

Referring to the method clickHandler() in my java file. This eliminated the need for the setOnClickListener() method.

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to pass [`View.OnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to this function, which is a listener that will get called once the button is clicked.

To do that, you can either:

1. Declare this listener in the layout XML, with the button, as specified in Button 4 in [this site](http://remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a69/Different-Ways-To-Handle-Clicks.html).
2. Create an instance of `View.OnClickListener` and pass it to setOnClickListener method as in the example below (Taken from [android site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) which is a great source):

   ```
   // Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
   private OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
         // do something when the button is clicked
       }
   };

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedValues) {
       ...
       // Capture our button from layout
       Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.corky);
       // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
       button.setOnClickListener(mCorkyListener);
       ...
   }
   ```

Since `View.OnClickListener` is an interface, your activity may implement it as well, and be itself the listener, in this case, you will pass the activity instance(`this`) to the `setOnClickListener` method, but this is just one option, and not that recommended IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a .NET background, I struggled with the same thing at first.  It's just a different syntax than .NET as java doesn't support properties, or events like I was used to.  Here's a simple example of how to do this using a class level click listener variable...

```
@Override
private void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    myButton.setOnClickListener(this.genericButtonListener);
}

private OnClickListener genericButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    //v represents your button
   }        
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a concrete class here. For example:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // your code here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29), you will notice it takes [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) as parameter. If you need five separate listeners, which you are not going to use anywhere else, you can pass an anonymous class implementing onClick(View v), like this

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //do required actions here
    }
});
```